# How to append into next line in Windows batch file

Tags: windows, mongodb, javascript, windows-batch

I am using a windows batch file that will output a .js file into csv.

The .js file is a mongo query.

```
mongosh --host 10.1.0.1:27017 --username "username" --password "password" --authenticationDatabase admin --quiet C:\ActiveUsers1.js > C:\ActiveUsers.csv 
mongosh --host 10.1.0.1:27017 --username "username" --password "password" --authenticationDatabase admin --quiet C:\ActiveUsers2.js >> C:\ActiveUsers.csv
mongosh --host 10.1.0.1:27017 --username "username" --password "password" --authenticationDatabase admin --quiet C:\ActiveUsers3.js >> C:\ActiveUsers.csv
```

Sample result for each .js file

```
ActiveUsers1.js = 10
ActiveUsers2.js = 15
ActiveUsers3.js = 20
```

What I want to have on my ActiveUsers.csv file should be:

```
10
15
20
```

What I am getting is:

```
101520
```

I just upgraded into mongosh and I am not encountering this when using the old mongo shell (mongo).

Is there a way that I could control this on a .bat file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `echo.` after each mongosh to append a carriage return after each line.

```
    mongosh --host 10.1.0.1:27017 --username "username" --password "password" --authenticationDatabase admin --quiet C:\ActiveUsers1.js > C:\ActiveUsers.csv 
    echo.  >> C:\ActiveUsers.csv  
    mongosh --host 10.1.0.1:27017 --username "username" --password "password" --authenticationDatabase admin --quiet C:\ActiveUsers2.js >> C:\ActiveUsers.csv
    echo.  >> C:\ActiveUsers.csv
    mongosh --host 10.1.0.1:27017 --username "username" --password "password" --authenticationDatabase admin --quiet C:\ActiveUsers3.js >> C:\ActiveUsers.csv
    echo.  >> C:\ActiveUsers.csv
```

Comment: Hi @RealHowTo I got it to work. However there is a single space after the ActiveUsers1.js and ActiveUsers2.js is there a way to remove this?

Comment: Okay I got it to work.

I just removed the spacing after echo.  >> C:\ActiveUsers.csv into

echo.>> C:\ActiveUsers.csv